# SQL server - converting string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a column that contains dates and times in the format `08-JAN-19 09.35.58.173000000 AM` to `datetime`. I've included the code I've tried below - the code commented out is currently not working.

```
SELECT [last_updated_at]
    , SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 1, 9)
    , convert(datetime, SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 1, 9), 103) as Date
    , SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 11, 18)
    --, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 11, 18), 103) as Time --This fails
    --, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 1, 9), 103) + convert(datetime, SUBSTRING([last_updated_at], 11, 18), 103) as DateTime --final output datetime column
FROM #temp_dates
```

Comment: Can you change the schema?

Comment: I can, but not sure why that would be required? I tried the below solution from @Vlam and it worked!

Comment: Y2K was 21 years ago. Why are we repeating this blunder?

Comment: The root cause of the issue is the schema is wrong. If you can change the schema I suggest you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
select convert(datetime, substring(replace(replace('08-JAN-19 09.35.58.173000000', '-', ' '), '.', ':'), 1, 18))
```

Before you can convert a string to datetime, your string must conform to certain patterns as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with your data is that you need the time portion of your date to look like this: `2019-01-08 09:35:58.173` instead of `2019-01-08 09.35.58.173` (the dots after the hour and minute need to be colons instead of dots.

```
--==== Original formatting
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20) = '08-JAN-19 09.35.58.173000000'

--==== Solution
SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(@date,13,1,':'),16,1,':') AS DATETIME);
```

Note that this truncates (not rounds) to the nearest millisecond so,  09:35:58.173 becomes 09:35:58.100. If milliseconds are an issue then a bit more finagling will be required.